# How to setup a quota for the whole "Mysite" webapplication in sharepoint 2007?

Tags: my-site, 2007, quota

How to setup a quota for the whole "Mysite" webapplication in sharepoint 2007?

Update:
Is it possible in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Under my knowledge so you cannot set up the quota for an entire web app.. this is limited to site collection scope only.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this indirectly by limiting the size of your content databases.  Here's an example:

25 Mysites, each with a site collection quota of 2GB.
Set your content database up pre-sized to 50GB with auto-grow disabled.
Since you have control over the amount of content databases you are dictating how much space that web application can utilize.